# Change action group with modifier key

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have an action group with a number of actions inside it. Similar to the list of run configurations that appears when you press `Ctrl + Shift + F10`, I want a different action (or a variation of the action) to be executed when the user holds `Shift` while selecting an action.

Sadly, neither the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html) nor the [code examples](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins) were able to help me much. I wasn't able to find the source code of the above-mentioned run configurations action group either.

Of course, I've tried the obvious solutions:

- Checking the value of `event.getModifiers()` inside `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`.
- Adding a `KeyListener` to the popup that contains the list of actions.

While the first solution works when the action is *clicked* on in the menu, it doesn't work when selecting it with `Shift + Enter`. In fact, I can't even catch any key events because they seem to be caught by the speed search instead.

How do I change an action group's behaviour based on modifier keys?

Comment: If you are talking about `ListPopup` then I have hacked it like this: https://github.com/krasa/FrameSwitcher/blob/2c8b3b1a3ef1496e3a2b91fc1936aff817ea8fed/src/krasa/frameswitcher/FrameSwitchAction.java#L221-L255

Comment: I wasn't explicitly using a `ListPopup`, but casting my popup to one seemed to work. However, now I'm having trouble with the `DataContext`. Your `getDataContext` returns a `DataContext`, but that context doesn't have a value for the editor in it. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Then you were using ListPopup, otherwise, it would not work. No idea, you have to delve into the IntelliJ code.

Comment: Maybe this is all you need: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/9c423653e22dffd866a18c25a3b83b566e831e8d/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/execution/actions/ChooseRunConfigurationPopup.java#L130-L136

Comment: It wasn't _all_ I needed; I also had to create a `KeyEvent` to use as `handleSelect`'s second argument to let the action know about the modifiers. I'll add an answer to my question in a minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Meo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685796/meo) I've found an answer.

I had the following code to create a popup containing a list of actions:

```
final ListPopup popup = JBPopupFactory.getInstance()
        .createActionGroupPopup(...); // some parameters here
```

By changing that code to the following, pressing `Shift + Enter` will select the currently highlighted option and pass the correct modifiers to the action's `actionPerformed` method:

```
final ListPopupImpl popup = (ListPopupImpl) JBPopupFactory.getInstance()
        .createActionGroupPopup(...); // some parameters here

popup.registerAction("invokeAction", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift ENTER"),
        new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
                final KeyEvent keyEvent
                        = new KeyEvent(popup.getComponent(), event.getID(),
                                       event.getWhen(), event.getModifiers(),
                                       KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED,
                                       KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN);
                popup.handleSelect(true, keyEvent);
            }
        });
```

---

Additionally, to change the title of the menu based on whether the key is being held:

```
popup.registerAction("shiftReleased", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released SHIFT"), new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
        popup.setCaption("Normal title");
    }
});
popup.registerAction("shiftPressed", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift pressed SHIFT"), new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
        popup.setCaption("Shift is pressed title");
    }
});
```